# Asp.Net MVC:How to get selected option from DropDownListFor in Action on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have dropdownlist in Asp.net form and after selected option on submit doesn't getting value in Action.

Not getting what i m missing and selected options not retrieving in Action .Here is the code

**ViewPage**

```
<div class="inner-box">

        @using ICommonInterfaces.Model
        @model LoginModel
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ApplicationSwitcher", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
        {
          @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ApplicationNames, new SelectList(Model.ApplicationNames, "TenantId", "ApplicationId"), "Select Application",
       new { @class = "textboxStyle", placeholder = "Select your application...", autofocus = "autofocus",
         autocomplete = "on", onkeypress = "btnFocusActivate(this, event)", id = "un" })
          <input type="submit" value="NEXT" class="rectangle" id="submitNext" disabled="disabled" />
        }       
</div>
```

**Model**

```
namespace ICommonInterfaces.Model
{
    public class LoginModel
    {
        public List<TenantApplicationNames> ApplicationNames { get; set; }
    }

    public class TenantApplicationNames
    {
        public string TenantId { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**On Submit HomeController Action**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ApplicationSwitcher(LoginModel loginModel)
    {
      var applicationNames = loginModel.ApplicationNames; // Count zero
      Console.WriteLine(applicationNames.Count)//0
    }
```

what is the reason not getting selected options?How to get it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the method to POST and get the value of selected item using Request.Form["nameOfYourDDL"]

Like:

```
<div class="inner-box">

    @using ICommonInterfaces.Model
    @model LoginModel
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ApplicationSwitcher", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
      @Html.DropDownListFor("ddlTest", m => m.ApplicationNames, new SelectList("ddlTeste", Model.ApplicationNames, "TenantId", "ApplicationId"), "Select Application",
   new { @class = "textboxStyle", placeholder = "Select your application...", autofocus = "autofocus",
     autocomplete = "on", onkeypress = "btnFocusActivate(this, event)", id = "un" })
      <input type="submit" value="NEXT" class="rectangle" id="submitNext" disabled="disabled" />
    }
```

And in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ApplicationSwitcher(LoginModel loginModel)
{
     var selectedValue = Request.Form["ddlTest"].ToString
}
```

Comment: Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ICommonInterfaces.Model.TenantApplicationNames>' to 'string'

Answer (score 0):

I test the form that is generated by `@using (Html.BeginForm()`. In controller, `loginModel` receives data with the type of array. In order to get the drop-down list's value in the controller, this code need to be modified.

In ViewPage, `m.ApplicationNames` need to be changed to array. `m.ApplicationNames[0].TenantId`

```
<div class="inner-box">

    @using ICommonInterfaces.Model
    @model LoginModel
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ApplicationSwitcher", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ApplicationNames[0].TenantId, new SelectList(Model.ApplicationNames, "TenantId", "ApplicationId"), "Select Application",
     new
     {
         @class = "textboxStyle",
         placeholder = "Select your application...",
         autofocus = "autofocus",
         autocomplete = "on",
         onkeypress = "btnFocusActivate(this, event)",
         id = "un",
     })
        <input type="submit" value="NEXT" class="rectangle" 
         id="submitNext" @*disabled="disabled"*@ />
    }
</div>
```

Result.
[image]